# backbonejs never ending collection inside model

Tags: backbone.js

Why is backbonejs creating a lot of collection inside a model and i don't know when it stops.

Take this example from http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-collection/. If you look into the console and keep opening the d object there's always a 'collection' object inside it which just repeats the the same object all over again.

I don't know if this is a bug or something but I am not really confident this is normal.

Someone please enlighten me. Thanks.

```
var Song = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: "Not specified",
        artist: "Not specified"
    },
    initialize: function(){
        console.log("Music is the answer");
    }
});

var Album = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Song
});

var song1 = new Song({ name: "How Bizarre", artist: "OMC" });
var song2 = new Song({ name: "Sexual Healing", artist: "Marvin Gaye" });
var song3 = new Song({ name: "Talk It Over In Bed", artist: "OMC" });

var myAlbum = new Album([ song1, song2, song3]);
console.log( myAlbum.models ); // [song1, song2, song3]
```

@ryan

yeah, I understand that a model may contain a reference to its collection. But it's kinda weird to have this kind of chained object that seems to have no end. The object tree is something like this:

```
[d, d ,d]
   0 > d
        > collection
            > models
                 0 > d
                      > collection
                           > models
                                0 > d
                                     > collection
                                           > models
                                                  0 > d
                                                   ...
                                                   keeps on and on and on
```

why is this so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong. They are just references. Every `Song` contains a reference to its collection, `Album`, once it is added to that collection.

Update. Maybe [this simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/hMwqd/) will help you understand nothing is abnormal. This is basically what backbone is doing. It's only purpose is to make it easy to navigate `collection -> user` or navigate `user -> collection`.

```
var site = { name: 'stackoverflow' };
var users = [{ name: 'pneftali' }];
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    users[i].site = site;
}
site.users = users;
console.log(site.users);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my question above to illustrate further my point.

Comment: i see. it made sense now after a while. models contain a reference to its collection, therefore it will look like an endless loop when viewed on the console. thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Every `model` has reference to the `collection`. And every `collection` has to have references to its `models`. Javascript holds only reference to the collection. Developer toolbar just shows you the details of the reference. They are not actually nested into each other. There are the same objects. You can confirm that from the model `cid` that does not change down the chain.